# getting OVER_QUERY_LIMIT geocoder.geocode

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm building a page that drops pins on a map and display's a div containing information for homes for sale in an area.

Currently, I'm getting "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" when I console.log the status.

Here's the code. The error happens about halfway down with the geocode.geocoder:

```
/* properties is res.data from an get(). */

if(properties.length > 0) {

    let propertyObj = properties.reduce((r, c, i, a) => {
      (c.property_name in r) ? r[c.property_name].push(c) : r[c.property_name] = [c];
      return r;
    }, {});

    console.log(propertyObj);

    /* Let's center our map based on the 1st instance's zip */

    MapsApi().then((maps) => {
    const geocoder = new maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({
      'address': `${properties[0].zip}`
    }, (results, status) => {
       const tempMap = new maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: results[0].geometry.location,
          zoom: 10,
          scrollwheel: false
        });
        console.log(properties[0].zip);

        /* Here establish the section Headers */

        let propertyString = `<div class="container">`;
        Object.keys(propertyObj).map((c) => {
          propertyString += `
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 properties">
            <h2>${c}</h2>
            </div>
          </div><div class="row">`;

          /* Here we'll create a <div> for each property in the array */ 

          let subPropertyString = propertyObj[c].reduce((r, c) => {
            r += `<div ~Div Content~
              </div>`;

              /* Let's drop a pin for each property on the map */
              /* below is where we're hit with the query limit */

              setTimeout(() => { geocoder.geocode({ 'address': `${c.address} ${c.city}, ${c.state} ${c.zip}` }, (results, status) => {
                  console.log(status, "making marker");
                  const marker = new maps.Marker({
                  map: tempMap,
                  position: results[0].geometry.location,
                });
                const info = new maps.InfoWindow({
                  content: `<a href="http://url.com/${c.pdf_location}" target="blank"><img src="http://url.com/${c.img_location}" alt="${c.address}"></a><p>${c.address}, ${c.address2}</p>`
                });
                marker.addListener('click', () => {
                  info.open(tempMap, marker);
                });
            })}, 100);
              return r;
          }, "");

          /* Let's close up each of these <div>'s */

          propertyString += `${subPropertyString}</div>`;
        });
        propertyString += `</div>`;
        allpropertiesContainer.innerHTML = propertyString;

        allpropertiesJumbotronDiv.innerHTML = `<div> ~Div Content~
        </div>`;
    });

  });

  allpropertiesTitle.innerHTML = `For ${propertiesType.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}${propertiesType.slice(1)}`;

  }
```

What Happens: the Subpropertystring 's are created perfectly. Once we hit the geocode.geocoder(), that's when we hit the limit.

As you can see I added a setTimeout in hopes to slow down the geocode process, but no luck.

This is where I need your help. How can I slow down that geocode so we don't surpass our query limit? I'm I putting the timeout in the wrong place?

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: Geocode each home once and store the coordinates for future use

Comment: There is a 50 requests per second, but also a 2500 per day. Perhaps you have passed the second one as well. So you cannot do anything until next day (*unless you pay*). AS @charlietfl says you should really only geocode once for each property and store the info you want.

Comment: @charlietfl & Gaby aka G. Petrioli, you don't think setTimeout() will resolve it? I'll look at recoding some of this to only geocode once, too

Comment: For per second limits ... probably. But why wait? There are numerous services to do bulk geocoding through and do it once and store the data which makes it instantly available to user. Also easier to search a stored collection based on distance when the coordinates are available. Plus likelihood of running into daily limits goes way down

Comment: @charlietfl - I'm sure you was this, but I'll point it out in case anyone else missed it. The first geocode is only running one address, properties[0], then from there going through the cycle of all the addresses. I think that would cause the query to be hit, I'm hoping there's a solution that doesn't require me to re-write the page :/ ha.

Comment: @charlietfl Do you have any examples or leads to the other services? I can't wait to resolve this...then I'm finished! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are encountering an **OVER_QUERY_LIMIT** response code while using some JS service, you may be encountering the limit per user session. There's a note under the usage limits documentation saying:

> Service requests are rate-limited per user session, regardless of how
>   many users share the same project.

See the **[Maps Javascript API Services limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage#usage-limits-for-google-maps-javascript-api-services)**.

Try to include a delay such as **setTimeout()** or consider using **[Google Maps Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start)** for batch requests.

For this kind of issue, you can also file it at **[Google Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/)**.

> Issue Tracker is a tool used internally at Google to track bugs and
>   feature requests during product development. It is available outside
>   of Google for use by external public and partner users who need to
>   collaborate with Google teams on specific projects.

To learn more, you can check **[Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/)**.

Comment: Hey @rafon, thanks for the answer, it’s the js api. I used a timeout function and it was still having the issue. I’m going to have to use the geocoding web services api

Comment: You are welcome mate. If you have any further clarifications about Google Maps API, just file an issue at Google Public Issue Tracker. :). Btw, if my post helped you, please accept/upvote it. Thanks :)